# My table is not conforming to the IEEEtran caption table format

Tags: tables, captions, ieeetran

I have the following code which produces the first attached Table. But as you can see in the table, both the table label and the caption all fall on the same line:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi

\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{mathtools, cases}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{eqparbox} % for the second example
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\meq}[2]{%
  \eqmakebox[#1][s]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
}


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

%\let\emptyset\varnothing
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!bp]
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of overall performances on both datasets}
\label{tab:default}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Datasets}                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{In-House}                                                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{NSL-KDD}    \\ \hline
DR                       & ACC                      & FPR                     & K  & DR      & ACC     & FPR    \\ \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{99.75\%} & \multirow{8}{*}{99.72\%} & \multirow{8}{*}{0.06\%} & 1  & 90.53\% & 96.14\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 2  & 94.22\% & 97.65\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 3  & 95.47\% & 98.16\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 4  & 96.10\% & 98.41\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 5  & 96.48\% & 98.57\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 10 & 97.25\% & 98.87\% & 0.02\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 20 & 97.57\% & 98.88\% & 0.22\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 30 & 97.68\% & 98.40\% & 1.11\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But what I want is a table with the caption format below:

[image]

How do I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: \captionsetup{justification=centering, labelsep=newline}

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKormylo, your suggestion solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- cause of your problem is package `subcaption`. do you really need them? if not simple delete it and your problem will disappear
- if you need `subcaption` than you need mimic IEEEtran table caption set up already in document preamble (see *mwe* below)

off-topic:

- resize table to  `0.5\textwidth` is not good solution. with this the table is wider then text in a column. if you persist to resize table, then: `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{....}`
- instead of resizing is better redesign a table to fit column width (see *mwe* below)

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=centerlast,
                     labelsep=newline,
                     font=sf,
                     textfont=footnotesize}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathtools, cases, empheq}
%\usepackage{eqparbox} % for the second example
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
%\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\newcommand{\meq}[2]{%
  \eqmakebox[#1][s]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Evaluation of overall performances on both datasets and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text}
\label{tab:default}

\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|*{7}{X |}}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Datasets}                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{In-House (\%)}                                                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{NSL-KDD (\%)}    \\ \hline
DR                       & ACC                      & FPR                     & K  & DR      & ACC     & FPR    \\ \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{99.75} & \multirow{8}{*}{99.72} & \multirow{8}{*}{0.06} & 1  & 90.53\ & 96.14 & 0.00 \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 2  & 94.22 & 97.65 & 0.00 \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 3  & 95.47 & 98.16 & 0.00 \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 4  & 96.10 & 98.41 & 0.00 \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 5  & 96.48 & 98.57 & 0.00 \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 10 & 97.25 & 98.87 & 0.02 \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 20 & 97.57 & 98.88 & 0.22 \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &
                         & 30 & 97.68 & 98.40 & 1.11 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}%

\bigskip
original table:
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Datasets}                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{In-House}                                                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{NSL-KDD}    \\ \hline
DR                       & ACC                      & FPR                     & K  & DR      & ACC     & FPR    \\ \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{99.75\%} & \multirow{8}{*}{99.72\%} & \multirow{8}{*}{0.06\%} & 1  & 90.53\% & 96.14\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 2  & 94.22\% & 97.65\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 3  & 95.47\% & 98.16\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 4  & 96.10\% & 98.41\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 5  & 96.48\% & 98.57\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 10 & 97.25\% & 98.87\% & 0.02\% \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 20 & 97.57\% & 98.88\% & 0.22\% \\ \cline{4-7}
                         &                          &                         & 30 & 97.68\% & 98.40\% & 1.11\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\end{table}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

*note:*
in preamble i delete all packages load twice and comment others not relevant to this *mwe*

Comment: For me, this captionsetup didn't quite get me to the IEEEtran journal format. I had to use `\captionsetup[table]{textfont={sc,footnotesize}, labelfont=footnotesize, labelsep=newline}`. But thanks for the tip on `labelsep`!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @John Kormylo's comment, I inserted the code `\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelsep=newline}`
inside the table, as shown below, and it solved the problem.

```
\begin{table}[!bp]
\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelsep=newline}
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of overall performances on both datasets}
\label{tab:default}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Datasets}                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{In-House}                                                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{NSL-KDD}    \\ \hline
DR                       & ACC                      & FPR                     & K  & DR      & ACC     & FPR    \\ \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{99.75\%} & \multirow{8}{*}{99.72\%} & \multirow{8}{*}{0.06\%} & 1  & 90.53\% & 96.14\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 2  & 94.22\% & 97.65\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 3  & 95.47\% & 98.16\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 4  & 96.10\% & 98.41\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 5  & 96.48\% & 98.57\% & 0.00\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 10 & 97.25\% & 98.87\% & 0.02\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 20 & 97.57\% & 98.88\% & 0.22\% \\ \cline{4-7} 
                         &                          &                         & 30 & 97.68\% & 98.40\% & 1.11\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```